# JPA best practices with @Temporal types

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

As we know Java date/time types are mutable. So we should encapsulate them if we want to avoid side effects.

I'm looking for a way which allows me to use these data types in JPA 2.0 and achieve the encapsulation goal at the same time.

In my practice I often use a pattern like this piece of code:

```
// imports are omitted 

@Entity
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class MyEntity {
    private Integer id;

    @Access(AccessType.FIELD)
    private Calendar createdAt;

    public MyEntity() {
        createdAt = Calendar.getInstance();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Transient
    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt.getTime();
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt.setTime(createdAt);
    }

}
```

Are there better ways to do that?

Thanks in advance.
Have a nice day.

Comment: Are you just trying to prevent the value of the property from being changed outside of the setter? Because Calendar is also mutable. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: @Perception You're completely right. I don't want the temporal property to be changed outside.

Comment: Ok thought so just wanted to clarify. The method you are using looks fine for this use case.

Comment: Can't you create a new Date object and return it from the getter?

Answer (score 0):

Date being mutable is a design quirk we all have to live with. And we have learned to live with it, by pretending that Date is immutable and not ever manipulating it (and also Sun made it easier by slapping some deprecations on there).

Writing defensive code is no good when you're protecting the code against yourself and trusted coworkers. I hope nobody is planning to do the wrong thing on purpose!